# Intellij edit online project intime

Tags: intellij-idea

I've 2 Ubuntu PCs on my home network. 1 is Desktop PC. and another 1 is laptop.

Desktop PC's IP is 192.168.10.10, OS is 12.04.4 lts
laptop PC's IP is 192.168.10.11, OS is 14.04 LTS

I want to edit the code of Desktop PC from my laptop using my home network by using Intellij

e.g ABC project is setup at Desktop PC. I want to edit those ABC project from my laptop.

Could I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can :

1) enable **VNC** or another similar tool that allow you to remote access the Desktop PC from you laptop

2) use a **shared directory** on the network that contains all the files of the project. Can be inside the laptop / desktop or an external disk connected to the home network or another server.

3) use something like **Dropbox**. You would need a bit of tweaking as you should have just have in  Dropbox the source files without the output and temporary files

4) use something like **GITHUB** where you can push/pull the code from one machine or another

I used **Dropbox** for similar cases and be sure do **not** include the .idea folder or idea specific files **.ipr**, **.iml**, **.iws** as they may contain machine specific paths.